# How to retrieve Nested Relationship in Laravel View

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

I'm new to laravel, but learning along the way..  Now I have 3 Tables [ courses, units and lessons ]

Courses has multiple Units and each unit has multiple lessons

Database Tables look something like this :

**courses** 
id 
crs_name 
..

**units**
id
course_id
unit_title

**lessons** 
id
course_id
unit_id
lesson_title

Relationships are defined as follows :
Unit Model

```
public function course(){return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');}
```

Course Model

```
public function units(){return $this->hasMany('App\Unit');}
public function lessons(){return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson');}
```

Lesson Model

```
public function course(){return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');}
public function unit(){return $this->belongsTo('App\Unit');}
```

This is my Controller [ I'm sure the problem is here as I can't define the nested relationship ]

```
    public function singleCourse($id)
{ 
    $course = Course::find($id);
    $reviews = Review::where('course_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(30)->paginate(10);
    $lessons = Lesson::where('course_id', $id)->take(15);
    $units = Unit::with('lessons')->where('course_id', $id)->take(15);
    return view('courses.course', compact('course', 'reviews', 'lessons', 'units'));
}
```

In my View I managed to retrieve the course Units, but can't get lessons of each units and when I try anything else, I get errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO4y0.jpg)

My View

```
@foreach($course->units as $unit)
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                          <h3 class="accordion-heading">
                            <a href="#shippingOptions" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="shippingOptions">
                              <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
                               {{$unit->unit_title}}<span class="accordion-indicator"></span>
                            </a>
                          </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse show" id="shippingOptions" data-parent="#productPanels">
                        @foreach($unit->lessons as $lesson)

                          <div class="card-body font-size-sm">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between border-bottom pb-2">                           
                              <div>
                                <div class="font-weight-semibold text-dark"><i class="czi-video"></i> {{{$lesson->lesson_title}}}</div>
                                <div class="font-size-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> 1h 20m</div>
                              </div>

                            </div>

                          </div>
                          @endforeach
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      @endforeach
```

Would really appreciate any help with the controller and View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, You have to make few changes as `with` is use when we redirecting to a new URL and flashing data to the session as [explained here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data). So you can replace your controller with given below:

```
public function singleCourse($id)
{ 
    $course = Course::with(['lessons', 'units'])->find($id);
    $reviews = Review::where('course_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(30)->paginate(10);
    $lessons = $course->lessons()->take(15);
    $units = $course->units()->take(15);
    return view('courses.course', compact('course', 'reviews', 'lessons', 'units');
}
```

To get lessons of unit you have to define a relation in unit model:

```
public function lessons()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson');
}
```

And to get specific unit lessons you have to do in your blade:

```
$unit->lessons
```

Here your find code for blade file will be :

```
@foreach($course->units as $unit)
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
  <h3 class="accordion-heading">
    <a href="#shippingOptions" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="shippingOptions">
      <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
       {{$unit->unit_title}}<span class="accordion-indicator"></span>
    </a>
  </h3>
</div>
<div class="collapse show" id="shippingOptions" data-parent="#productPanels">
@foreach($unit->lessons as $lesson)

  <div class="card-body font-size-sm">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between border-bottom pb-2">                           
      <div>
        <div class="font-weight-semibold text-dark"><i class="czi-video"></i> {{{$lesson->lesson_title}}}</div>
        <div class="font-size-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> 1h 20m</div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hello Vinot thanks and how should I retrieve the lessons that belong to specific unit in the blade view ?

Comment: I did all the changes and  added foreach unit lessons and I got the same old error [ Invalid argument supplied for foreach ]

Comment: Please update your question with the changes you have made.

Comment: Update Done Vinod

Comment: Please add `lessons` relation method to `Unit` model.

Comment: WOW .. I am sooo dumb !!! I didn't have the has many relationship of Lessons inside the Unit model ... Now it's working VINOD thanks for your patience :)